# Why is Storage returning a local URL, despite it being uploaded to a public S3 bucket?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I am using Laravel to upload files to an S3 bucket that were uploaded via a standard HTML form.  The files are being uploaded successfully, however I am unable to get the full URL for the uploaded file.

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) the following code should return a full URL:

```
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $filename = $request->get('filename');

    if($file->isValid()) {
        $extension = $file->extension();

        // Store local and on S3
        $path = $file->storeAs('wysiwyg', $filename .'.'. $extension, 's3');
        $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);

        return ['success' => $path];
    }
```

However, I am actually getting a relative URI being returned in `$url`.  For example, if I pass `wysiwyg/image.jpg` as the `$path`, then an image is uploaded to S3 at that destination, but `Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);` just returns `wysiwyg/image.jpg`, rather than the fully qualified domain (`http://test-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wysiwyg/image.jpg`).

The default disk is set to s3, and I can confirm the image is being uploaded to S3 successfully.

How can I get the fully qualified domain as part of this uploaded?  I'm aware I can store it in the config and just append a path myself, but that doesn't help me if I'm managing multiple buckets programmatically.

I'm using Laravel 5.5.

Thanks

Comment: You're returnung `$path`, not `$url`.

Comment: try this `Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($path);` or `storage_path('s3/'.$path);`

Comment: @tkausl- you're right.  Sigh. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return ['success' => $path];`

Should be:

`return ['success' => $url];`